# Determine the unknown value of 2 unit vectors

Tags: vectors

The unit vectors a and b are such that a.b = $\frac{2}{3}$ . Determine the value of a.(a + 2b).

I am not sure where to start with this question.

Comment: Use linearity of the dot product and the fact that you have unit vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, recall that dot product is [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Properties), and therefore
\begin{align}
\vec{\bf a}\cdot {\big(\vec{\bf a} + 2\, \vec{\bf b} \big)} &= \vec{\bf a} \cdot  \vec{\bf a}  + 2\,\big(\vec{\bf a}\cdot \vec{\bf b} \big)
\end{align}

Second, since unit vectors have length $1$ $\left(\text{ i.e. }\; \vec{\bf a}\cdot \vec{\bf a} =1\,\right)$ and $\vec{\bf {a}}\cdot \vec{\bf b} = \dfrac23$, we get

\begin{align}
\vec{\bf a}\cdot {\big(\vec{\bf a} + 2\, \vec{\bf b} \big)} &= \vec{\bf a} \cdot  \vec{\bf a}  + 2\,\big(\vec{\bf a}\cdot \vec{\bf b} \big) = 1 + 2\,\dfrac23 = \dfrac73
\end{align}

Comment: Why is $\vec{\bf a}\cdot {\big(\vec{\bf a} + 2\, \vec{\bf b} \big)} = \vec{\bf a} \cdot  \vec{\bf b}  + 2\,\big(\vec{\bf a}\cdot \vec{\bf b} \big)$ ?

Comment: @SplitInfinity Thank you for catching my mistake!